# Writing Range in excel.

Tags: vba, excel

```
colname = Split(Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colname).End(xlUp).Row
ws.("?" & Lastrow).Copy ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

**i** is a number, which is converted to column name. I need a range starting from number 4 for eg if i =1, I need **Range("A4" & Lastrow)**. I have lastrow and I can get A , but how do I make it A4

Comment: `Range("A4" & Lastrow)`  do you mean `Range("A4:A" & Lastrow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Row as integer
Dim Col as integer
Row = 4
Col = 1
Range(Cells(Row, Col), cells(LastRow, Col))
ws.Range(Cells(Row, Col), Cells(LastRow, Col))
```

Comment: ws.Range(Cells(4, i) & Lastrow).Copy  ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)   . This Doesn't work

Comment: Nope, wouldn't expect it to. It's not what I put in my answer, either. If you're going to use it that way, you need Range(**Cells**(), **Cells**()). You need to specify both the top-left and bottom-right corner of your range by using a `Cells()` reference for each. Tacking `& Lastrow` in there will likely just throw an error.

Comment: Sorry but I have one more thing to ask. Why does ws.Range using this fromat does not work while without it works, means it considers active sheet.

Comment: @Jain, I've added an example that's right out of a worksheet that I'm currently developing. It works just fine like that as a reference. If you're still having issues with it, you should probably open a new question with your current code and a very specific description of what's not working.